# what is the difference between declaring constant in an interface and in class java

Tags: java

1)What is the difference between two static variable below code.

```
Class A{
public static final String  X = "XYZ";
}


interface A{
String X = "XYZ";
}
```

2)if both static are variable declaration  are same then which one is the efficent.

ie

```
Class A{
public static final String  X = "XYZ";

void print(){
System.Out.Println(X);
}
}
```

OR

```
interface B {
String X = "XYZ";
}


 Class A implements B{

    void print(){
    System.Out.Println(X);
    }
    }
```

Comment: yes i tested it but its  a doubt i need to clarify

Comment: I think the question is which one is more useful. because by declaring it in interface you can improve the visibility of the variable. I all depends on the requirement though

Comment: constants in a class don't have to be public, but in an interface they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Both the constants have same meaning. By default the fields declared in interface are `public static final`.

2) Fields in interface should not be preferred. (until unless you are very much confident that another interface won't have field with same name).

```
interface A
{
    String X = "XYZ";
}

interface B
{
    String X = "ABC";
}

class C implements A, B
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(X); // Ambigous X
    }
}
```

3) Efficiency won't be affected by where you place constant; in class or in interface.

Answer (score 5):

1. There's no difference between the fields. From [section 9.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3):

   > Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.
2. There's no difference in performance, because in both cases the compiler will "inline" the field value anyway: at execution time, it won't access the fields anyway. That's only the case because you're using `String` though; if the field were a type other than a primitive type or `String`, the code *would* access the field... but I wouldn't expect this to ever have a *signficant* impact on performance, and you shouldn't worry about it. Write the clearest code you can instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no difference as far as the kind of field that's created. Both ways create a constant field.
2. The difference in efficiency is negligible, if any. You should care more about network latency and the like when it comes to efficiency. That will affect your application 10 million times as much as this, and that's probably being conservative. With things this trivial, readability is far more important than efficiency, so do whatever is clearest.

Answer (score 0):

Pecularity is that **ALL** variables denfined in the Interface are `public` `final` without specifically being said so.

Comment: Ermm ... this doesn't address the Question.  If (hypothetically) you could declare variables in an `interface` that were not (implicitly) public and final, that would be a bad thing.  1) An interface is designed so that anything that access the interface can access its members.  Non-public members contradicts that.  2) Non-static fields in an interface would effectively be equivalent to public fields in every class that implements it.  That is *bad design* for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no difference in performance.
2. This is more of a design decision rather than performance oriented.
3. My choice for declaring constants will be in order:

a. Enum 
b. Interface 
c. Classes

I remember this issue was briefly discussed in "Effective Java" book.